# Dynamic Linq not working - Select not being applied

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

I've tried several possibilities and did a proper research on blogs and answers on stackoverflow. It may be me but I just can't get this dynamic linq query working.

I've a controller on a Web Api project with the following projection and route defined.

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<Company, CompanyLightListDTO>> AsCompanyLightListDTO = x => new CompanyLightListDTO
{
  Name = x.Name,
  Id = x.Id
};

[Route("Test")]
[ResponseType(typeof(CompanyLightListDTO))]
public IQueryable<CompanyLightListDTO> GetTest(string name=null, string 
email=null, bool? isSupplier=null, bool? isCustomer=null)
{
  IQueryable<Company> query = db.Companies;
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    query.Where(c => c.Email.Contains(email));

  if (isSupplier.HasValue)
    query.Where(c => c.isSupplier.Equals(isSupplier));

  if (isCustomer.HasValue)
    query.Where(c => c.isCustomer.Equals(isCustomer));

  // Return ??
}
```

I've tried several returns. All of them ignore all the previous where.() and return all Companies.

> not working because return all companies. The Where clauses are not applied

```
return query.Include(c => c.Name).Select(AsCompanyLightListDTO);
return query.Select(AsCompanyLightListDTO);
```

The only I can get this method working is by doing

```
return db.Companies.Include(c => c.Name)
  .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name)
    && c.Email.Contains(email)
    && c.isSupplier.Equals(isSupplier)
    && c.isCustomer.Equals(isCustomer))
  .Select(AsCompanyLightListDTO);
```

but I would like to have a dynamic linq Query so that I could do these type of calls:

> api/Companies/Test/name=somename&isCustomer=True
>   api/Companies/Test/isCustomer=True&isSupplier=True
>   api/Companies/Test/name=somename&email=someemail

Any noble developer willing to help a new coder on the block?

Best regards
DWilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try replacing `GetTest` to this?

```
IQueryable<Company> query = db.Companies;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Email.Contains(email));

if (isSupplier.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(c => c.isSupplier.Equals(isSupplier));

if (isCustomer.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(c => c.isCustomer.Equals(isCustomer));
```

`Queryable` Methods(`Select`, `Where`, etc) retrurn new `IQueryable` instance.

Comment: Thank you, what a simple mistake... I forgot to assign the variable.. I definitely need to take a break after this 12h maraton

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is when you're doing:

```
query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));
```

it isn't actually assigning it back to the IQueryable.  The IQueryable is lazy loading, which means it isn't actually running the query until you iterate through the results or call ToList() or something.  So each time you're modifying your query variable, you're not saving what your modifying it to.  To solve this you just need to do:

```
query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));
```

Then at the end you return query.  Then once you load the results it should have all your modifications.

Comment: Thank you I mentioned in the above answer that I was tired and forgot to assign the variable. I still can't believe.

Comment: both answers are correct, is it possible to mark both as correct?