# DbSet<> does not contain definition for GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this search method that gives me some headache

```
var query = await dbContext.Tasks; // Gets the error here!
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<BKR.BOL.Task>> Search(string Name, string Description)
        {
            MyDbContext dbContext = new BKR.DAL.Context.MyDbContext();
            var query = await dbContext.Tasks; // Gets the error here!
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Name == Name).ToList();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Description == Description).ToList();
            }

            return MapToBOL(query, dbContext);
        }
```

```
public static List<BKR.BOL.Task> MapToBOL(IList<DAL.Task> data, MyDbContext db)
        {
            var query = from d in data

                        select new Task(d, db)
                        {
                            TaskId = d.TaskId,
                            TaskTypeId = d.TaskTypeId,
                            TaskStatusId = d.TaskStatusId,
                            CustomerId = d.CustomerId,
                            ResourceId = d.ResourceId,
                            Deleted = d.Deleted,
                            Name = d.Name,
                            Description = d.Description,
                            StartTime = d.StartTime,
                            EndTime = d.EndTime,
                            CreatedBy = d.CreatedBy,
                            CreationTime = d.CreationTime,
                            ChangedBy = d.ChangedBy,
                            ChangedTime = d.ChangedTime
                        };
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have `await` there? What do you think it does?

Comment: it makes the db call async :-)

Comment: You should use: `query = await query.Where(x => x.Name == Name).ToListAsync();` instead.

Comment: `Tasks` is a property - not a `Task`.

Comment: Whenever I call a ToList method, the query is executed. The method should be able to handle more Where conditions before execution

Comment: @JanGravgaard no it does not.

Comment: @JanGravgaard: `ToList()` call executes the query.

Comment: Also can you please add code for `MapToBOL`?

Comment: Is `Task` disposable?

Comment: Have a look at this video, fastforward to time 1.46.06
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-blazor-webassembly-and-web-api-on-net-6-by-building-a-shopping-cart-app/
Here they use "await" before the db context.....

Comment: No BKR.BOL.Task class is not disposable...

Comment: @JanGravgaard I looked at that video at the timestamp you've specified and he's not awaiting the context, he's awaiting the task that's returned from a call to `SingleOrDefaultAsync`.

Comment: @JanGravgaard, the class `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` **implements** `IDisposable`.  However, Microsoft has taken special steps to allow us to freely ignore this.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I highly doubt that `Task` in OP is the one from BCL. I would argue that it is user defined type (`BKR.BOL.Task`) which happens to have the same name.

Comment: You really shouldn't use some random video to learn EF Core. Have a look at the official microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?source=recommendations&tabs=netcore-cli), or look at some tutorial [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/) or [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Linq not working - Select not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017834/dynamic-linq-not-working-select-not-being-applied) (maybe not the best dupe, but couldn't find a better one at a quick glance.)

Answer (score 0):

`dbContext.Tasks` is a collection of `task` objects, not a query, and is not awaitable.

If you want the data, you'll need to create a query, such as...

```
var query = await dbContext.Tasks.ToListAsync();
```

Note that `ToListAsync` returns a `Task` (the built-in one, not your database type), and so is awaitable.

If you want to handle multiple `Where` clauses, you can do it like this...

```cs
var query = dbContext.Tasks;
if (something) {
  query = query.Where(t => t.Id == "Ferret")
}
// Other clauses can go here
var results = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Whenever I call a ToList method, the query is executed. The method should be able to handle more Where conditions before execution

Comment: You can do whatever you like before you call `.ToListAsync()`, see my updated answer

Comment: I have reached to this solution.....what you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

I have reached this solution.....what do you think about that?

```
public static async Task<List<BKR.BOL.Task>> Search(bool Deleted, string Name, string Description, System.DateTime? StartTime, System.DateTime? EndTime, System.DateTime CreationTime, System.DateTime? ChangedTime)
{
    MyDbContext dbContext = new BKR.DAL.Context.MyDbContext();
    var query = dbContext.Tasks.AsQueryable();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Name == Name);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Description == Description);
    }

    return await MapToBOLAsync(query, dbContext);
}


public static Task<List<BKR.BOL.Task>> MapToBOLAsync(IQueryable<DAL.Task> data, MyDbContext db)
{
    var query = from d in data
                select new Task(d, db)
                {
                    TaskId = d.TaskId,
                    TaskTypeId = d.TaskTypeId,
                    TaskStatusId = d.TaskStatusId,
                    CustomerId = d.CustomerId,
                    ResourceId = d.ResourceId,
                    Deleted = d.Deleted,
                    Name = d.Name,
                    Description = d.Description,
                    StartTime = d.StartTime,
                    EndTime = d.EndTime,
                    CreatedBy = d.CreatedBy,
                    CreationTime = d.CreationTime,
                    ChangedBy = d.ChangedBy,
                    ChangedTime = d.ChangedTime
                };
    return query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: This looks fine, but why are you creating a new `Task` at the end? Unless there's something you're not showing, you are getting a `List<Task>` in the `Search` method, then converting it to an identical `List<Task>` in the `MapToBOLAsync` method. Can't see any benefit in this.

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel, not following you.....MapToBolAsync maps from a DAL.Task to a BOL.Task

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that! Confusing having the same name in two different namespaces. I tend to make it clearer when one is a db entity and the other is a DTO, but I see what you mean now. In that case, it looks fine to me.